# Is it possible to use Capacitor with the new "/app" structure of NextJS 13?

Tags: next.js, cross-platform, capacitor, next.js13, capacitor-plugin

I am struggling to use [Capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/getting-started) for my NextJS 13 application which uses new the [App router](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing).

Is it possible to somehow create an "out" folder and a "index.html" when building the application while using the new "/app" structure of a NextJS13 project?

I read the [Capacitor documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/getting-started) and seen blogs such as [this one](https://blog.rahulbharati.dev/master-the-10-minute-10-step-guide-converting-your-next-js-app-to-mobile-with-capacitor-1269bde2f1b4) without success.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use NextJS's static export feature, but it's quite troublesome. Because in this mode, many of NextJS's core features are not available, requiring significant modifications.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports